# Would you allow this type of query?

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'm exploring using an ORM tool in our development shop, and in particular Entity Framework 4.0.  Since we work with VERY large databases, I'm a bit concerned about the query's it generates.

Doing something simple like getting clients with an address in a state looks like below.

As a database developer or admin would you allow this?  Is it as bad as it looks?  Assume every join is on a clustered index.

```
    SELECT 
[Project2].[ClientKey] AS [ClientKey], 
[Project2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project2].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled], 
[Project2].[ChangeUser] AS [ChangeUser], 
[Project2].[ChangeDate] AS [ChangeDate], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[AddressKey] AS [AddressKey], 
[Project2].[ClientKey1] AS [ClientKey1], 
[Project2].[AddressTypeCode] AS [AddressTypeCode], 
[Project2].[PrimaryAddress] AS [PrimaryAddress], 
[Project2].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 
[Project2].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], 
[Project2].[City] AS [City], 
[Project2].[State] AS [State], 
[Project2].[ZIP] AS [ZIP]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[ClientKey] AS [ClientKey], 
    [Distinct1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Distinct1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Distinct1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled], 
    [Distinct1].[ChangeUser] AS [ChangeUser], 
    [Distinct1].[ChangeDate] AS [ChangeDate], 
    [Extent3].[AddressKey] AS [AddressKey], 
    [Extent3].[ClientKey] AS [ClientKey1], 
    [Extent3].[AddressTypeCode] AS [AddressTypeCode], 
    [Extent3].[PrimaryAddress] AS [PrimaryAddress], 
    [Extent3].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 
    [Extent3].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], 
    [Extent3].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent3].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent3].[ZIP] AS [ZIP], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[AddressKey] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[ClientKey] AS [ClientKey], 
        [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled], 
        [Extent1].[ChangeUser] AS [ChangeUser], 
        [Extent1].[ChangeDate] AS [ChangeDate]
        FROM  [Common].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [Common].[ClientAddresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ClientKey] = [Extent2].[ClientKey]
        WHERE  (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER('D'), UPPER([Extent1].[LastName])) AS int)) > 0) AND ([Extent1].[IsEnabled] = 1) AND ([Extent2].[City] IS NOT NULL) AND ((UPPER([Extent2].[City])) = (UPPER('Colorado Springs'))) ) AS [Distinct1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Common].[ClientAddresses] AS [Extent3] ON [Distinct1].[ClientKey] = [Extent3].[ClientKey]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[ClientKey] ASC, [Project2].[FirstName] ASC, [Project2].[LastName] ASC, [Project2].[IsEnabled] ASC, [Project2].[ChangeUser] ASC, [Project2].[ChangeDate] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Is it the ORM generating those queries, or are the queries the result of the way certain C# statements are written? The presence of the UPPER() leads me to believe the latter...

Comment: What is the LINQ query that this is generated from?

Comment: I dont remember exactly this example but it was something like  var q = from client in context.Clients.Include("ClientAddresses")
                    where client.ClientAddresses.All(c => c.ZIP == "80923")
                    select client;

Comment: or  var query = from t1 in context.Clients.Where(clientSpec.SatisfiedBy())
                        join t2 in context.ClientAddresses.Where(addrSpec.SatisfiedBy()) 
                            on t1.ClientKey equals t2.ClientKey
                        select t1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inner join addresses to clients ...

```
INNER JOIN [Common].[ClientAddresses] AS [Extent2] 
   ON [Extent1].[ClientKey] = [Extent2].[ClientKey]
```

with condition on city ...

```
AND ((UPPER([Extent2].[City])) = (UPPER('Colorado Springs')))
```

now left join addresses again?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Common].[ClientAddresses] AS [Extent3] 
  ON [Distinct1].[ClientKey] = [Extent3].[ClientKey]
```

The left join is redundant since a row must already exist to match the condition.

Also it is selecting distinct rows in the inner query which is probably unnecessary if the tables are normalized

I would not trust the ORM to generate optimal queries.

Comment: I'm really hoping for "decent" on the core domain and procedures for the more complicated stuff.  Maybe i'm too hopeful.  =)

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an unnecessary derived table, which almost doubles the length of the query. It is unlikely to have a significant effect on the run time performance, so it's not worth worrying about.

More troubling from a performance perspective is the use of functions in the WHERE clause that will prevent the use of indexes.

```
WHERE ...
AND ((UPPER([Extent2].[City])) = (UPPER('Colorado Springs')))
```

It should just be this with an appropriate case-insensitive collation:

```
WHERE ...
AND [Extent2].[City] = 'Colorado Springs'
```

But it may not be a problem in practice.